# Collision detection tutorials

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-mechanics

I'm supposed to develop a Java game using AWT and Applet libraries. I'm stuck with the concept of "collision detection". If you can help me with any tutorials that explain the concept (how it works) or give examples (source code), I'd be grateful.

Comment: there is a lot! search google.com :)

Comment: Questions that just generate lists are not usually a good fit for GDSE.  I usually point new devs at http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique.html, can't "answer" ad there's no way I can list every tutorial ever; hence why this is a bad fit for GDSE.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do, but I'll just keep it simple.

[This tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/sessions/collision-detection-and-reaction/) explains basic forms of collision detection. They're formatted for AS3, but the concepts behind them can be used for any language.